# Adding Angular Material to Nx Workspace not working

Tags: angular, angular-material, nrwl-nx

I'm trying to add angular-material to my nx-workspace.

I've tried this command:

```
nx add @angular/material
```

And it generated this Error Response:

> Cannot find project '@angular/material'

Then I've tried this command:

```
npx nx g @angular/material:ng-add --project=groups-app
```

But it generated another Error Response:

> Unable to resolve @angular/material:ng-add.
> Cannot find module '@angular/material/package.json'

Does anyone know how I can fix this issue and how I can add angular-material to my nx-workspace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually do this.

Follow https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started and manually do each step. e.g. Install

- Angular Material
- the Component Dev Kit (CDK)
- Angular Animations

Add the styles direct in `project.json` or import in `apps\groups-app\src\styles.scss`. Below I've added prebuilt styles.

```
    "build": {
      "executor": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "outputs": ["{options.outputPath}"],
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/apps/groups-app",
        "index": "apps/groups-app/src/index.html",
        "main": "apps/groups-app/src/main.ts",
        "polyfills": "apps/groups-app/src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "apps/groups-app/tsconfig.app.json",
        "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
        "assets": [
          "apps/groups-app/src/favicon.ico",
          "apps/groups-app/src/assets"
        ],
        "styles": [
          "apps/groups-app/src/styles.scss",
          "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css"  <----
        ],
        "scripts": []
      },
```

This works for libraries too.

If you get lost, create a new separate (non nx) angular only app and see what `ng add @angular/material` does and replicate in your nx app.

Comment: I already tried the npm install command: `npm i @angular/material`. 
But it threw another error: 


npm ERR!  code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: groups-webserver@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/animations@14.2.12
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/animations
npm ERR!   @angular/animations@"~14.2.0" from the root project

Comment: install them at the same time `npm i @angular/material @angular/cdk @angular/animations`. I presume `groups-webserver` is your own lib. You may need to update this first, update the version and then it'll be `npm i @angular/material @angular/cdk @angular/animations groups-webserver@1.0.0`

Comment: If I add styles into serve instead of build, I get the following error: 'styles' is not found in schema

Comment: @SarenTasciyan you're best off asking a new question (if you can't find answer) specific to your error